# Get the sum of int values in a Dictionary<string, List<int>>()

Tags: c#, linq

How would I get the sum of all the ints in each list?

Code:

```
var teamScoreDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
```

Example data:

```
teamScoreDict.Add("Blue", new List<int>(){34,53,57,22,68,78,12,28});

 teamScoreDict.Add("Red", new List<int>(){64,66,22,73,25,45,36,21});
```

Comment: Have you made your own research first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should make a new dictionary, with the name of the team and the total sum of all of the values in the list

```
teamScoreDict.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value.Sum())
```

Comment: Can you send me to a tutorial about the shorthand you use.... I am used to the from "from X in Y where whatheverIneedOf X select X.I" syntax but that seems outdated...

Comment: Hi @user2888973, Have a look at this MSDN article. It's a nice introduction about the differences between query syntax (from f in f.Something) and method syntax (f => f.Something)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
var sum = teamScoreDict.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Sum();
```